# Access X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME in Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, httpcontext, blazor-webassembly

In the Blazor WebAssembly app that I'm currently working on, the username(X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME) is accessed in Startup.cs through HttpContext.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
     app.Use(async (context, next) =>
     {
        var username = context.Request.Headers["X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME"];
        // Perform some business logic to check if user has access to the site.
     });
}
```

I want to access the same **username** in my RazorPage so that I could utilize it. In my client side, I have injected HttpContextAccessor and attempted to access the username.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

@code {
    private string username;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        userName = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME"];
    }
}
```

However, on running the application, I obtain

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot provide a value for property 'HttpContextAccessor' on type 'HoshiApp.Client.Shared.Page'. There is no registered service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor'.
```

Is there any way I can directly access the username mentioned in Startup?

Comment: in your `Startup.ConfigureServices` you need to have this `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` to register the `IHttpContextAccessor`

Comment: I had already added services.HttpContextAccessor() but still receive the same error. (I have edited my post to include Startup.ConfigureServices.)